# SAPUI5 chart not visible...when running from within the portal

Tags: sapui5

I have a really bizarre one here...I have developed and deployed to my back end system a launchpad application that currently works OK. Part of this application is a report that, based on certain filters, returns a table and a chart (see snapshot below).

[image: Correct output]

After finishing deployment next step is configuring the app so it runs from the launchpad within the SAP portal. Not familiar with the portal, another colleague undertook the task, application is now running from within the portal as well. With one exception - the chart above is not visible (see 2nd snapshot below).

[image: Erroneous output]

Noticing the "No Data" message and NO exception in the Chrome debugger, thought as a good idea to debug the OData methods in the back end. To my big surprise, found out that while filters pass to the method just fine both for table and chart (two different entities but almost identical and accepting exactly the same parameters) when running outside portal, when running from within (the portal) parameters "get lost" on their way to the chart entity - no parameters for the chart method. See snapshots below and pay attention to the `IT_FILTER_SELECT_OPTIONS` at the bottom right.

Outside portal (parameter table filled)
[image: Correct debugger]

Within Portal (parameter table empty)
[image: Erroneous debugger]

Furthermore, the filter table passed to both OData tables is common, you can see the code underneath - just two lines: one for table and one for chart binding.

[image: binding code]

Closing with a clarification. Mentioned above that there are no errors in the debugger when calling the back end methods. There are actually a couple of them but they take place during the initialization of the app and do not seem to affect anything else in the app, which aside a set of reports has a lot of data operations (dialogs, tables etc), everything else works fine. These errors can be seen below.

[image: initialization messages]

Does this situation ring any bells to anyone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, it was a deployment issue...